# My soundboard app plays sound on the simulator, but not the device

Tags: ios, xcode, audio

I am making a soundboard app on Xcode 4.2. When i run the app on the simulator, the sound plays fine. But, when i run it on the device, no sound will play. My code is below.

```
- (IBAction)awhaaa:(id)sender {

    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"awhaaa", CFSTR ("wav"),NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

is the file really named awhaaa.wav?  the simulator, since it's running on your mac, is case-insensitive.  the phone is case-sensitive, so if the file is aWhaaa.WAV or awHAaA.wAv, it will work in the simulator but not on the device.

Comment: Yes, that is the actual file name. I double checked to make sure the spelling/case was correct.

Comment: One possibility is the wav file itself.  Try converting it to CAF, or MP3 and see if it still gives you trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:  on the device, go into settings and turn up the volume on Sounds->Ringer and Alerts

Then try again.